# Entity Framework using SQL_VARIANT

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, indexing

I have the following example where I am querying a entity on a INT field. Below is a example of my scenario:

```
int test =1;
var listExample= _db.EntityTable.Where(x => x.StatusId == test).ToList();
```

When i look at the SQL generated, it using SQL_VARIANT as the variable declaration, therefore does not use the index correctly on table which results in a entire table scan.

Below is an example of the SQL generated:

```
DECLARE @p__linq__0 AS SQL_VARIANT;
SET @p__linq__0 = NULL;

SELECT 
[Extent1].[id] AS [id], 
FROM [dbo].[tbl_table_example] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[status_id] = @p__linq__0
```

Is there anyway to get EF to try and define the variable as the property type that been queried?

Comment: Did you use the ADO.NET EF wizard, or did you hand code the classes? It is generally the case that if you use EF wizard, it will determine the types rather than doing boxing, and unboxing in your example.

Comment: Handled in in Classes. I have a Entity Class and Configuration class to associate with DB table.

Comment: Please post those definitions as well.

Comment: Class Property:
public int? StatusId { get; set; }

Configuration:


            Property(p => p.StatusId)
            .HasColumnName("status_id");

            HasOptional(p => p.Status)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(p => p.StatusId);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that's just a bug or limitation in the way Visual Studio IntelliTrace generates a SQL batch corresponding to the SqlCommand actually executed.  I reproduced this, but looked at the SQL sent through SQL Profiler, and it looked correct:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [x].[Id], [x].[StatusId]
FROM [EntityTable] AS [x]
WHERE [x].[StatusId] = @__test_0',N'@__test_0 int',@__test_0=1
```

Also EF logging reports the correct parameter type:

```
SELECT
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id],
    [Extent1].[StatusId] AS [StatusId]
    FROM [dbo].[EntityTables] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[StatusId] = @p__linq__0


-- p__linq__0: '1' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)

-- Executing at 8/1/2018 9:41:32 AM -05:00

-- Completed in 20 ms with result: SqlDataReader
```

Whereas the IntlliTrace output (note the warning on the first line) was:

```
--Type and value data was not available for the following variables. Their values have been set to defaults.
DECLARE @p__linq__0 AS SQL_VARIANT;
SET @p__linq__0 = NULL;

SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[StatusId] AS [StatusId]
    FROM [dbo].[EntityTables] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[StatusId] = @p__linq__0
```

Comment: do you think that would be because of the boxing? I feel like the variable goes to SQL server as boxed, and the conversion probably then happens. Otherwise, if passed as integer, I would assume the index would be used.

Comment: The index should be used.  Whether the value ever gets boxed is irrelevant.  As you can see from the Profiler trace the parameter is sent as an `int`, and an index can be used unless the actual column type is `smallint` or `tinyint`.

Comment: Hi David, I replicated what you did and you seem to be correct that the issue is with visual Studio. thanks